# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'function'

Tags: pandas

My df info is below.

- I need to convert `Age` column into numeric
- In case age is less than 18, replace it with mean of age values.
- In case age is having some random string, replace it with mean of age values.

df_ca_.info()

```
Age         100 non-null object
```

`df_ca_['Age'].astype(int)`

got error `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'function'`

df_ca_["Age"] = pd.to_numeric(df_ca_["Age"])

`TypeError: Invalid object type at position 13` because of following thing

```
df_ca_.loc[14] have `function AAX`
```

I tried the below code got error 
df_ca_.Age = df_ca.Age.loc[(df_ca.Age < 18)] = np.mean('Age')

`TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type`

Comment: The error says your column `df_ca_['Age']` contains function object at position 13. Did you check your input?

Comment: yes its there, i mentioned in question also

Comment: I mean whether you checked why `function AAX` is in your dataframe.

Comment: i dont know, data was not clean, if any string is there we can remove with np.mean of the Age

Comment: try `df_ca_['Age'] = pd.to_numeric(df_ca_['Age'], errors='coerce')` first, then `fillna` after.

Comment: errors='coerce' will remove the row right? how to do with out removing like if  type(str)?np.mean.Age

Comment: no, it will place `nan` in the rows where it could not convert the value to a number.

Comment: @QuangHoang  can you tell me is not working `df_ca_.Age = df_ca_.Age.loc[(df_ca_.Age < 18)] = np.mean()`   TypeError: mean() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'

Comment: replace `np.mean()` by `df_ca_.Age.mean()`

Comment: Quang Hoang the super awesome :)